# Media Player In android

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

In Android How much bits/bytes are playing Media player in a second? .Purpose of this question is when i converting the 5 mb audio file to byte array .I can get only approximately
1.5 mb of file when media player playing the file  from the beginning to the end of the file .I read the bytes using  a class that extends asynchronous task. How can i get the full bytes of that file .How can solve this issue?

Comment: The bitrate is determined by the content, not the player. How is the media player involved in your conversion?

Comment: i just use only Media Player class object , that is     MPplayer.setDataSource("/mnt/sdcard/test1.mp3");

Comment: Your question is not so clear. What are you exactly doing?

Comment: I wish to convert playing audio  file to byte array until i pause the audio and i need that byte array to convert to audio file to get a new file.If i didn't paused then i need the original audio !!!

Answer (score 0):

Your approach will fail when you encounter mp3s with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_bitrate
You may could read the file beforehand and analyse it. Some material can be found with google, like: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MP3#File_structure